# Write multiple statements in swig expression tag?

Tags: swig-template

i am tring to write multiple line in my swig expression tag but conditions are not evaluting,
but if i write all the statements in different tag then it is working.
Please find following example :

```
{% set promo_class = "whatone" %}

{% if (loop.index % 2) == 0 %}

{% set promo_class= promo_class +" mhxxl"; %}

{% endif %}
```

Following is not working for me, while above one is

```
{%

set promo_class = "whatone";

if ( loop.index % 2 ) == 0

set promo_class= promo_class +" mhxxl";

endif;

%}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block statements are not part of the Swig Template language. Nowhere in the documentation does it show that as an example or an available syntax style.